# backbone: render this collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var Text = Backbone.Model.extend({});   

Texts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Text,
    url: '/data.json',
});

var TextsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.render();
    },
    el: "#Texts",
    template: _.template($('#TextTemplate').html()),
    render: function(e){
        _.each(this.model.models, function(Text){
            var TextTemplate = this.template(Text.toJSON());
            $(this.el).append(TextTemplate);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
})

var Texts = new Texts();
Texts.fetch();
var TextView = new TextsView({collection: Texts});
```

this gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined` and does not display anything on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `this.model.models` should be `this.collection`

In your render method in your view, you should use `this.collection.each` instead of `_.each` function.

```
render: function(e){
    this.collection.each(function(Text){
        var TextTemplate = this.template(Text.toJSON());
        $(this.el).append(TextTemplate);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

If you want to use `_.each` function, then you will need to access the models array directly in your collection as @dfsq pointed out. This can be done by using `this.collection.models`.

```
render: function(e){
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(Text){
        var TextTemplate = this.template(Text.toJSON());
        $(this.el).append(TextTemplate);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here are some reasons your fetch call may not be working. First check that you are using a web server, since ajax requests may be blocked for security reasons using file system. I know this is blocked in Chrome unless you change a certain setting. Not sure about Firefox.

The second reason is that the fetch `call` is asynchronous. This means that mostly likely your data will not be loaded when you run `initialize`

This means you'll need to make the following adjustments. First you need to add a listener to the add event of your collection so that anytime an item is added, your view will be notified.

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this);
    this.render();
    // Listen to the `add` event in your collection
    this.listenTo(this.collection,"add", this.renderText);  
},
```

Next we need to add a function to your view that will render a single item

```
renderText: function(Text) {
    var TextTemplate = this.template(Text.toJSON());
    this.$el.append(TextTemplate);        
}
```

Also to answer your other question about the user of `this` in the each loop. The last parameter in the each function is the scope you want to use in the inside the callback function that executes. So if you use `this` as the second parameter, it allows you to access your viewing using `this`.

```
    this.collection.each(function(Text){
        var TextTemplate = this.template(Text.toJSON());
        $(this.el).append(TextTemplate);
    }, this);
```

If you don't add `this`, then you'd need to do this:

```
    var view = this;
    this.collection.each(function(Text){
        var TextTemplate = view.template(Text.toJSON());
        $(view.el).append(TextTemplate);
    });
```

Comment: Seems to me that it should be `this.collection.models`.

Comment: He's using Backbone, so `this.collection` refers to the `Texts` collection he created. That should make the loop work, but I guess you can access the models directly using `this.collection.models`. Didn't know that. Interesting.

Comment: Actually you are right @dfsq. If you use the underscore each method, then you do need to use `this.collection.models`. Must have changed recently. Anyway changed it to use the each method on the collection.

Comment: I'm saying because I just tested it :)

Comment: thank you for this answer. What is the purpose of using `this` as the second argument for the `_.each` function? I'm still confused why that is needed. I am a backbonejs noob.

Comment: @Gohn67 it still seems to be not showing anything on the screen. I am getting no errors raised. what do I need to do to make it display?

Comment: @KJW, Not sure if you fixed your issues, but I added some more information to my answer